# how to use the pivot table mode in acces 2013 forms

Tags: ms-access, pivot-table, office-2013

I was create a form in Microsoft Access 2010 from a table and load it in pivot table mode to watch the data in a Cube and i use it without any problem.
but this pivot table mode is disable in MS-Access 2013
Pls. Help Me.

Comment: You can't ( http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/officeitpropreview/thread/4260dc68-33a2-4044-8087-3ae4a6a9794f ) Use Excel.