# How to Use OFFFOWC ActiveX to Use Pivot Tables in MS-Access 2013 and Later

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Pivot tables have been deprecated in 2013.  The particular feature I need cannot be replaced in Excel or Crosstabs, it was only available in Access.  This post says there is no workaround.

[how to use the pivot table mode in acces 2013 forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480367/how-to-use-the-pivot-table-mode-in-acces-2013-forms][1])

But I found this code:

```
Private WithEvents pt As OffOwc.PivotTable
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Set pt = Me.myActiveXControl
End Sub
```

This requires referencing offowc.dll, which can be copied over from an earlier version of Access or downloaded from Microsoft.

In above code, the first statement works to create the object pt.

In the form load event, I can set the form pivot table as follows:

```
Set me.PivotTable = pt
```

But this statement gives a reference error and that is as far as I could get:

```
Set me.PivotTable.ActiveNew = pt.ActiveView
```

I'm aware that if I want this feature, I'm probably stuck using the 2010 runtime version until it no longer operates, but I thought maybe there was still some way to incorporate this old DLL so that I can move forward in current versions without losing this feature.